# Stop page refreshing when clickig a target _blank link

Tags: html, hyperlink

I want to put a link to a external page, but when I click on the link, which is meant to open a new tab, the original tab gets refreshed too while opening the new tab, I want to stop the refreshing since it has a session open and refreshing it leads to the login form of my page, is there any solution to this?

```
<a style='text-decoration: none;' target="_blank" href="(link to 
the external web page)" >Visit</a>
```

I've been searching and I just can't find a way to fix this, not sure if I missed something or if I'm not searching with the right words, is just a normal `<a href='extlink'>` link that leads to another web page

Comment: Please share the code that you're using. You can use https://jsfiddle.net/ to build an example

Comment: There's nothing in the link that would cause a refresh of the page. There might be a JavaScript listener attached to it that is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I were told that could be a javasccript attached to the link, and that was the issue, I was using a class that refreshes the tab onclick without realizing,thanks for the suggestion